# How to check if user owns resources before CRUD

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to clean up my controller actions, and I'm not sure how best to proceed. I have an edit action where I receive the resource via route model binding. I want to check that the user owns this resource before modifying it, and if not, redirect to a generic index route

```
public function show(Document $document)
{
    //  This works fine, but I've repeated this for all other 
    //  actions where user views or modifies resource. How do
    //  I share this functionality with view/show/delete?
    if ($document->user_id !== Auth::id()) {
        return redirect('documents');
    }

    return view('documents.show', compact('document'));
}
```

How can I implement this behavior, without repeating these lines for each action, e.g., show/edit/view? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a middleware that checks if the authenticated user id equals the `$request->document->user_id` in the `handle` method and apply the middleware in the contructor method of your controller for only (show, view, delete)

Here's an example implementation

```sh
php artisan make:middleware DocumentsOwnerShip
```

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class DocumentsOwnerShip
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request->document->user_id !== auth()->id()) {
            return redirect('documents');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

And in your controller

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Middleware\DocumentsOwnerShip;

class DocumentsController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware(DocumentsOwnerShip::class)->only(['view', 'show', 'delete']);
    }

    public function show(Document $document)
    {
        return view('documents.show', compact('document'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I did consider this and I will take a look at how to implement.

Comment: I'll edit the answer with an example implementation

Comment: Great, that's exactly what I'm looking for. I've up-voted, but my vote did not increase the count for this answer (signed up just now). Thanks for the help

Comment: You can accept the answer by clicking the checkbox, thanks

Comment: @aaronmarr I would also take a look at larvel's policies with the authorization methods [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authorization#via-controller-helpers)

Comment: @CaddyDZ awesome, yes I ended up using Policies instead as I realized the logic is slightly different for routes without the document model, which policies seem able to handle. Thanks for the help

Comment: Even better implementation